# AS3 Dictionary setPropertyIsEnumerable ignored

Tags: actionscript-3, dictionary, enumeration

Can someone explain to me why the Dictionary class ignores setPropertyIsEnumerable?

I found [this](https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/ASC-3980) bug at bugs.adobe, seems the prototype might be involved in some devious way

Here is some test code:

```
var obj:Object = {
    'a': 0,
    'b': 1,
    'c': 2
}

obj.setPropertyIsEnumerable('a', false)

trace("object\n")
for (var op:* in obj)
{
    trace(op)
}

var dict:Dictionary = new Dictionary()
dict['a'] = 0
dict['b'] = 1
dict['c'] = 2

dict.setPropertyIsEnumerable('a', false)

trace("dictionary\n")
for (var dp:* in dict)
{
    trace(dp)
}
```

Output of this is:

```
object

c
b
dictionary

c
a
b
```

Notice that the Dictionary is still enumerating the property "a" even though it was told not to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my guess... `Dictionary` is overriding `nextName` in order to return the keys of the dictionary.  It is using it's own implementation of it such that it is ignoring `setPropertyIsEnumerable`.

I can't prove it yet, but I am trying.  I thought I would throw out this hypothesis to see if it sparks anything.

Comment: Nope, I don't think this is the case.  It doesn't derive from `Proxy`, so it doesn't override `nextName`.  I wish `Dictionary` were part of Flex so we can look at the source code.  I wonder if it is a magic class in some way.

Comment: Hey Brian, It's good that you replied, It was Linq that sparked this question. the toDictionary method is generating a modified Dictionary. I think in this case a Dictionary wrapper is need until Adobe fix this bug. I'm considering this a compiler level bug.

Comment: I agree.  `length()` was added as a convenience.  I am pretty sure it can be removed safely. Possibly, a helper method should be added to ActionLinq in case somebody is relying on the behavior, but I doubt it.